# unittest tests reuse for family of classes

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have problem organizing my `unittest` based class test for family of tests. For example assume I implement a "dictionary" interface, and have 5 different implementations want to testing.

I do write one test class that tests a dictionary interface. But how can I nicely reuse it to test my all classes? So far I do ugly:

```
DictType = hashtable.HashDict
```

In top of file and then use `DictType` in test class. To test another class I manually change the `DictType` to something else.

How can do this otherwise? Can't pass arguments to `unittest` classes so is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I tackle this with standard `unittest` is by subclassing -- overriding data is as easy as overriding methods, after all.

So, I have a base class for the tests:

```
class MappingTestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    dictype = None
    # write all the tests using self.dictype
```

and subclasses:

```
class HashtableTest(MappingTestBase):
    dictype = hashtable.HashDict

class OtherMappingTest(MappingTestBase):
    dictype = othermodule.mappingimpl
```

Here, the subclasses need override only `dictype`.  Sometimes it's handier to also expose `MappingTestBase` use "hook methods". When the types being tested don't have exactly identical interfaces in all cases, this can be worked around by having the subclasses override the hook methods as needed -- this is the "Template Method" design pattern, see e.g. [this page](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/learning-python-design-patterns-through-video-lectures/) which has a commented and timelined collection of a couple of video lectures of mine on design patterns -- part II is about Template Method and variants thereof for about the first 30 minutes.

You don't have to have all of this in a single module, of course (though I often find it clearest to lay things out this way, you could also make one separate test module per type you're testing, each `import`ing the module with the abstract base class).

Comment: I am trying to use this pattern but am getting errors (e.g. `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`) because the `unittest` framework runs the tests within the context of `MappingTestBase` as well as the derived classes. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @PaulBaker, sure, you can build the test suite you want to run quite explicitly, e.g by using class `TestLoader`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader , e.g by subclassing it and overriding `getTestCaseNames` to return `[]` for classes whose test methods you don't want to run.  Or, you could decorate all test methods to just return if `self.dicttype is None`.  Both approaches work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [testscenarios](https://launchpad.net/testscenarios) which allows you to set a list called scenarios. The code then generates a version of the test class for each value/scenario in the list

See [the example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lifeless/testscenarios/trunk/annotate/head:/doc/example.py)

So in your case the scenarios would be a list like [ {dicttype:hashtable.HashDict}, {dicttype:otherimpl.class}, ] and use self.dicttype in your test code.

Comment: oh, so this can't possible with just standard unittest? very dissapointing :-(

Comment: Not yet - see http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/unittest2.shtml for what is being done